# Remove white space at the start of the string

Tags: string, actionscript-3

How I can remove whitespace from a string, but only if the white space is the first character?

For example:

Make this string `" Hi man I am bingo"`

to be this string `"Hi man I am bingo"`

Just remove the first whitespace in the string.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have RTRIM; how to make LTRIM with regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556603/i-have-rtrim-how-to-make-ltrim-with-regexp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringUtil.trim(myString)`
Removes all whitespace characters from the beginning and end of the specified string.

Comment: Thanks I will download this class and try it :)

Comment: in flex there is no need for download. Maybe in flash too, don't?

Comment: this helper resides in the `mx.utils`. so, i think, unless you reference the flex swc's the package is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var yourTxt:String " blah blah blah"
yourTxt.replace( '/^\s+', '')
```

This should replace 1 or more spaces at the start of the string.

I'm rather rusty on the old action script!

Dave